# databinding hidden (non visible) combo box in xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I have a problem binding data to a combobox that's in a secondary (not initially focused) tab.  Basically, I have a silverlight form with multiple tabs, whenever I move this combobox to the first (main) tab, the data is loaded and everything works as expected, but when this combo box is in a secondary tab that doesn't have focus initially on first load, the combo box has no data, however, if I data bind the combo box using c# in the code behind it has data!  Any ideas on how to solve this?

My binding in XAML (this doesn't work)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"  Height="24" Width="149"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

MyList is most likely empty when it's first bound.  Try using an event that is available when you switch to the next tab, to load MyList

Comment: Nope that's not the problem, I'm using an observable collection and firing off an event when the data is getting populated, the problem is the cmbbox is not picking it up because it didn't render yet, thus no binding when the data first got populated

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue...
The solution I found to solve the problem is the following:
Whenever your data source (datacontext) changes: iterate through all tab items, select each one, update layout and force rebind. At the end select back the initial tab item. Something like this (to do in an event handler firing when your data source changes (could be in loaded event in case of initial load):

```
var selectedIndex = tabControl.SelectedIndex;
foreach (TabItem item in tabControl.Items)
{
    tabControl.SelectedItem = item;
    item.UpdateLayout();
    DataContext = null;
    DataContext = ViewModel;  
}
tabControl.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
```